# Laravel = redirect page select tag onchange

Tags: laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/mypage/{id}/edit', 'MyController@edit')->name('mypage.edit.get');
```

on the home page,  i have this select tag:

```
<select name='record'>
  <option value='1'>Form One</option>
  <option value='2'>Form Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Form Three</option>
</select>
```

I need to redirect the page to my route name **mypage.edit.get** on the onchange event of my select tag.

please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would help:

```
$("[name='record']").on("change", function (e) {
    let edit_id = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/register/business/' + edit_id + '/edit';
});
```

Comment: the leading slash character solved my problem. i dont have that when i tried so my new URL was just appending on my current url, thus, page cannot be found. thanks so much! lesson's learned.